# Drupal front page error

Tags: drupal, migration

I have been attempting to migrate some Drupal content into another site. So far, everything was working... let's say, fine. You can imagine I have been moving so many things that, I was certain I was going to screw up at some point.

This morning I started getting a "page not found" in my front page. I went to "Site Information" and front was correctly referenced. I temporarily changed "mysite.com/front" to "mysite.com/node" and now, every time I want to return the path to "front" I get an access error and I get a "Page Not Found" in my front page. I have developed the habit to clear cache every time I do almost anything.

What would be the most common reason for this msg to appear? Read/write permissions somewhere?

I am using Drupal 6.2 with several modules and a custom theme, based on Zen.

Comment: Do you have a page with a path of "front" on the site? Or a URL alias defining front to be an alias for something?

Comment: 6.2 is too old version. Try to update your site to latest 6.x version.

Answer (score 1):

Laxman13 above brings up a good point. You were previously pointing the front page to the path "front" -- what node or function uses that alias?

If you go to admin/content/node you'll see all content -- are the nodes that you're expecting to appear on the front page there?

Are you logged in as UID=1 when you are doing all of this? If not do you have permissions set for anonymous users to view the content in these pages?

Comment: Well, guys, turns out that the previous developer had modified the front page with some php coding, so I was treating this "error" as a normal Drupal situation, but that was NEVER going to work. I used the Empty Page module and that helped me A LOT.